# OR-Tools Cost Function Integration

Tags: python, or-tools

I am modeling a problem similar to the job shop problem (tasks with start times, duration, and predecessors) and my objective is to minimize the makespan, with Python and OR-Tools.

**start[i]** is an integer decision variable that shows the period when task $i$ starts

`start[1] = 3` $\Rightarrow$ task 1 starts on period 3

**duration[i]** is a parameter that is the task $i$ duration (and is known)

`duration [1] = 2` $\Rightarrow$  task 1 takes 2 period to be completed

Now I want to integrate a cost function where if a task $i$ starts on a specific period and ends on period `start[i]+duration[i]`, the cost will be the sum of every period it's being worked on.

I have a cost matrix:

```
Cost[i,j] = [[ 1, 2, 3, 6, 8], 
             [5, 6, 7, 2, 1]]
```

**cost[1,1]** is the cost for task 1 if it's being worked on during period 1

So if task 1 has a duration of 2, and starts on period 1, then periods 1,2,3 will be the target periods, and the cost will be `cost[1,1]+cost[1,2]+cost[1,3] = 1+2+3` from the cost matrix.

I tried creating a binary matrix `BIN[i,start[i]:start[i]+duration[i]]` that uses `start[i]` and `duration[i]` and returns a  style matrix, where 1 if the task is in progress and 0 if not, so then I can pass the `cost[i,j]` and find the total cost for a scenario.

```
total_cost = model.NewIntVar(0,99999,'total_cost')
b = model.newboolvar('b')
    for i in range(alltasks):
        model.Add(start[i] != 0).OnlyEnforceIf(b)
        model.Add(start[i] == 0).OnlyEnforceIf(b.Not())

        model.Add(total_cost == sum(Cost*b)).OnlyEnforceIf(b)
        model.Add(total_cost == 0).OnlyEnforceIf(b.Not())
```

But that doesn't work at all...

If it can help in the understanding: My goal is to make the model choose the best period to start/end on a period knowing the duration is fixed and there is a cost to each period that this task will be worked on (so to reduce the cost)

Comment: "So if task 1 has a duration of 2, and starts on period 1, then periods 1,2,3 will be the target periods, and the cost will be cost[1,1]+cost[1,2]+cost[1,3] = 1+2+3 from the cost matrix.": since the duration is constant, couldn't you pre-compute $c_{jt}$ the total cost of task $j$ when starting at time $t$?

Comment: @aczi0, welcome to OR.SE. Would you please, how do you calculate the cost function as long as it needs to solve the problem to determine the start/compilation time of each task?

Answer (score 1):

If the duration is fixed, then the cost is only a function of the start.

I recommend looking at this [code sample](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/docs/integer_arithmetic.md#step-function) on how to encode a step function.
You can also just use an Element constraint.